# Null response, when I should get xml

Tags: java, xml, playframework, playframework-2.0

When I type certain URL I get xml file

```
<response>
   <result>something</result>
   <description>description</description>
</response>
```

When I try to recieve it using function on my server, I receive `[#document: null]` . My function is nearly identical to function from documentation, so I have no idea what might have gone wrong. Code:

```
public static play.libs.F.Promise<Result> locationControllerGET(String number) {
       String feedUrl = "https://somepath/?msisdn="+number;
       final play.libs.F.Promise<Result> resultPromise = WS.url(feedUrl).setAuth("user", "password").get().map(
                    new Function<WS.Response, Result>() {
                        public Result apply(WS.Response response) {
                            return ok(response.getStatusText()+" "+response.asXml());
                        }
                    }
            );
            return resultPromise;
        }
```

It outputs `OK [#document: null]`

I guess that I have some basic misunderstanding about what this code does, I think it goes to feedUrl, passes arguments from setAuth when asked for verification, and maps what the server returned in result. Am I wrong? If so, how can I do that?

Edit: What one should do, if one wants to get the content of website pointed by address, is use return `ok(response.getStatusText()+" "+response.getBody.toString());` .

Comment: If your edit is the solution, you should post it as an answer below, not in the question.

Answer (score 0):

What one should do, if one wants to get the content of website pointed by address, is use `return ok(response.getStatusText()+" "+response.getBody.toString());`